# Exporting $PSDefaultParameterValues from a script module in PowerShell Core

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

**How do you export `$PSDefaultParameterValues` from a script module in PowerShell Core?** *Every* way I've tried so far has resulted in the importing scope's `$PSDefaultParameterValues` being replaced with an empty hashtable (whether or not the importing scope had anything defined in it).

### Attempts So Far

The following is a summarized version of what all I have tried. Assume that the module is wholly contained in the file `$Env:TEMP\PSDefaultParameterValues.psm1`, which is imported via `Import-Module -Name (Get-Item "$Env:TEMP\PSDefaultParameterValues.psm1").FullName`. I have tried many of the following variations with both a populated and an empty `$PSDefaultParameterValues` in the importing scope.

```bsh
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:WhatIf'] = $true
Export-ModuleMember -Variable 'PSDefaultParameterValues'
```

```bsh
$PSDefaultParameterValues = $PSDefaultParameterValues
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:WhatIf'] = $true
Export-ModuleMember -Variable 'PSDefaultParameterValues'
```

```bsh
$PSDefaultParameterValues = $PSDefaultParameterValues.Clone()
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:WhatIf'] = $true
Export-ModuleMember -Variable 'PSDefaultParameterValues'
```

```bsh
$local:PSDefaultParameterValues = $PSDefaultParameterValues.Clone()
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:WhatIf'] = $true
Export-ModuleMember -Variable 'PSDefaultParameterValues'
```

```bsh
$script:PSDefaultParameterValues = $PSDefaultParameterValues.Clone()
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:WhatIf'] = $true
Export-ModuleMember -Variable 'PSDefaultParameterValues'
```

```bsh
Set-Variable -Name 'PSDefaultParameterValues' -Value ($PSDefaultParameterValues.Clone())
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:WhatIf'] = $true
Export-ModuleMember -Variable 'PSDefaultParameterValues'
```

```bsh
Set-Variable -Name 'PSDefaultParameterValues' -Value ($PSDefaultParameterValues.Clone()) -Scope Local
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:WhatIf'] = $true
Export-ModuleMember -Variable 'PSDefaultParameterValues'
```

```bsh
Set-Variable -Name 'PSDefaultParameterValues' -Value ($PSDefaultParameterValues.Clone()) -Scope Script
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:WhatIf'] = $true
Export-ModuleMember -Variable 'PSDefaultParameterValues'
```

### Environment

The test environment was started with `pwsh -Interactive -NoExit -NoLogo -NoProfile`. Its `$PSVersionTable` is as follows:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      6.2.1
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    6.2.1
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.17763 
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

### Edit (2019-06-15 03:45:58Z)

I had originally stated that both

```bsh
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:WhatIf'] = $true
```

and

```bsh
$global:PSDefaultParameterValues['*:WhatIf'] = $true
```

resulted in the importing scope's `$PSDefaultParameterValues` being replaced with an empty hashtable. That is incorrect.

After testing these two variations again using *exactly* the examples given here, the first variation does not appear to affect the importing scope's `$PSVersionTable`, and the second variation appears to modify it as desired. I do not have the exact code I used to test originally (much of my original testing was done *ad hoc* after having run into the problem but expecting to find a quick-and-simple solution), so I am unsure why I am getting a different result now.